# How to exit a repeat loop if no arguments are provided or command incorrect

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have created this script to keep checking disk usage in a direcorty every 2 seconds with command `du -sh`

So when I run the script with `./repeat.sh du -sh`  it outputs:

```
52K     .
52K     .
52K     .
etc ...
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true
do
        if cmd="$1" "$@"
        then sleep 2
fi
done
```

I am trying to alter it so that if no arguments are provided e.g. the `sh` bit or the command provided is incorrect it exits without doing anything but this bit is not working in the script. How do I set up these conditions to what I have ?

Thank you

Comment: just want to point out that [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) does almost the same thing, perhaps that would be suitable in your case: `watch -n 2 du -sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the validity of the command by first running it silently and validating its return code (since you're about to run it in a loop anyway, you sacrifice one execution to verify it):

```
$@ &>/dev/null
if [[ $? = 0 ]]
then
   echo "Valid command"
fi
```

As for checking arguments, this is a simple check of the `$2` argument:

```
if [[ ! $2 ]]; then
   echo "No arguments"
fi
```

Combining these features should get you what you want in your script.

Comment: Or just say `[ $# -gt 0 ] && $@ &>/dev/null && while true ; do ...` and so on.